# Filtering a dataframe with two conditions pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

Quite a simple question, have tried several things with no luck.

I'm trying to isolate age ranges of customers whose birth dates fall in a certain interval.

```
youth = cd.loc[cd.yearofbirth.isin([1996, 1997 1998, 1999]), "SALES"]
```

works fine however, some of the other intervals are larger (i.e. include 30+ years) and I don't want to write them all out but rather do a less than or equal to and a more than or equal to. i.e.

```
youth = cd.loc[cd.yearofbirth >= 1996 | cd.yearofbirth <= 1999, "SALES"]
```

but this line of code gives me a error

```
TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [float64] array with a scalar of type [bool]
```

A single inequality works fine, but its when combining it with a second which makes it error.

help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

You need to use brackets to separate the boolean conditions.
Moreover, it looks like you need the intersection (`&`) rather than the union (`|`) of conditions:

```
youth = cd.loc[(cd.yearofbirth >= 1996) & (cd.birth_year <= 1999), "SALES"]
```

This is because in Python `|` (or `&`) has [precedence](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/precedence-associativity) over `>=`, which explains your error.

This is also reported in the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html?highlight=boolean#boolean-indexing):

> Another common operation is the use of boolean vectors to filter the
>   data. The operators are: | for or, & for and, and ~ for not. These
>   **must** be grouped by using parentheses.

Finally, for this specific case you might not need multiple conditions at all, as you can use the [`between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) method:

```
youth = cd.loc[cd.yearofbirth.between(1996, 1999), "SALES"]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. One issue however is although no longer erroring, it doesn't quite work as i'd like. It returns ALL entries which are greater than 1996 and also all the entries that are less than 1999 as opposed to only those that lay BETWEEN the interval. any advice to amend this?

Comment: I guess you want to use AND condition (&) instead of OR (|), since you want the intersection

Comment: Glad it helped, I have edited the answer. Don't forget to upvote/accept if this solved your problem